# Stroke-dashoffset, posiiton stroke-dasharray

Tags: svg

I have 3 svg donut charts, each chart has a line created with stroke-dasharray altogether the charts add up to 100%.

I'd like each chart to start where the last one finishes so the first chart is from 0-60%. I'd like the second chart to start at 60% and go to 90% and the final chart to start at 90% to 100%

I'm trying to so this with stroke dashoffset but I can't work out how this works.

```html
<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
</svg>






<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="60"></circle>
</svg>







<svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>

  <circle class="donut" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="grey" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="10 90" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Found the answer = Circumference − All preceding segments’ total length + First segment’s offset = Current segment offset

Answer (score 4):

The circumference with a radius `r ="15.91` is equal to
`2 * 3.1415 * 15.91 = 99.96` ∼ `100`

`stroke-dasharray="60 40"`, where

`60` - dash
 `40` - `gap`

A positive value `stroke-dashoffset = 25` shifts the line counterclockwise by a quarter of a circle.
Since the default - `stroke-dashoffset = 0` circle will start at 90 degrees, that is from the `x` axis of the first quadrant

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  first chart is from 0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25">
  </circle>
```

- A negative value `stroke-dashoffset = -35` shifts the second, red
  circle clockwise to the end of the first green line`(25-60 = -35)`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  first chart is from 0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <!--  second chart to start at 60% and go to 90% --> 
 <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-35"></circle> 
   </svg>
```

- A negative value `stroke-dashoffset = -65` shifts the third, orange
  circle clockwise to the end of the second red line`(-35-30 = -65)`

```html
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
  <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
  <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
<!--  first chart is from 0-60% -->
  <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="green" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="60 40" 
          stroke-dashoffset="25"></circle>
  <!--  second chart to start at 60% and go to 90% --> 
 <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="red" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="30 70" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-35"></circle> 
 <!--  final chart to start at 90% to 100%  -->
 <circle class="donut-segment" 
          cx="21" 
          cy="21" 
          r="15.91549430918954" 
          fill="transparent" 
          stroke="orange" 
          stroke-width="3" 
          stroke-dasharray="10 90" 
          stroke-dashoffset="-65"></circle>    
    
    
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

1st chart is from 0-60%  => 60% offset 0%:

```
stroke-dasharray="60 40"
stroke-dashoffset="0"
```

2nd chart to start at 60% and go to 90% => 30% offset 60%:

```
 stroke-dasharray="30 70"
 stroke-dashoffset="-60"
```

final chart to start at 90% to 100% => 10% offset 90%:

```
 stroke-dasharray="10 90"
 stroke-dashoffset="-90"
```

```html
  <svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <!--  first chart is from 0-60%  => 60% offset 0% -->
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="60 40"
      stroke-dashoffset="0"
    ></circle>
  </svg>
  <svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <!--  second chart to start at 60% and go to 90% => 30% offset 60% -->
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="30 70"
      stroke-dashoffset="-60"
    ></circle>
  </svg>

  <svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <!--  final chart to start at 90% to 100% => 10% offset 90% -->
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="10 90"
      stroke-dashoffset="-90"
    ></circle>
  </svg>


  <svg width="15%" height="15%" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3"></circle>
    <!--  all charts -->
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="60 40"
      stroke-dashoffset="0"
    ></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="red" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="30 70"
      stroke-dashoffset="-60"
    ></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="grey" stroke-width="3"
      stroke-dasharray="10 90"
      stroke-dashoffset="-90"
    ></circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of explanation to help the OP understand what you've done?